# How to dynamically set which properties get bound to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

My DataGridView needs to support a number of types and these types may have any number of public properties, not all of which I want to display.

Can anyone suggest a way to dynamically customise a DataGridView's columns when binding a class a datasource? Is there an attribute that will tell a control whether to use a property as a column for example?

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default (with auto column generation enabled), it will simply obtain (via ComponentModel) the `[Browsable(true)]` properties, (or those that omit this attribute).

If this is the *only* use of binding for this data, you could add `[Browsable(false)]` to the properties you don't want to show. Note that this will also prevent regular data-binding (i.e. `TextBox`, `PropertyGrid`, etc) to those properties.

In reality, I expect it would be better to create your own attribute, and use that to find the properties you want to display via reflection (and build the columns yourself).